# Override text size of textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to set a text size in UserSetting to my textView programmatically; the problem is when it change with `myTextView.setTextSize(18)` once i return to my xml it go Back to default size, I don't want that instead i want to keep my own text size.

my TextView xml:

```
<TextView
                        android:id="@+id/MainText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                        android:text="long_lorem_ipsum_2"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_60"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"/>
```

Comment: save your own text size in `SharedPreferences` and retrieve it when you want to update the size

Comment: How can i do that, is there any exemple plz  @Amrnoid

Comment: see my Answer below

Answer (score 2):

use SharedPreferences  to save Your Own TextSize

code to save textsize in SharedPreferences:

```
  SharedPreferences  pref=getSharedPreferences("MyPref",MODE_PRIVATE);              
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();            
   editor.putFloat(FONT_SIZE_KEY,textSize);    // your textsize       
   editor.commit();
```

to retreive textsize Value from SharedPreferences

```
       SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
       float fontsize=prefs.getFloat(FONT_SIZE_KEY, 12);
```

Comment: thx for that .. So when i implemant SharedPreferences the size in TextView change and Stay to my own text size. ?

Comment: after select size save the value in shared and retrieve it in onCreate method after create textview object in activity

Comment: i tried that code but i have to retrieve the zise each time .. i dont want that , i want that size Preference the be kept to my textView ! @Amrnoid